# jquery UI : how to define icon for button in HTML

Tags: jquery-ui

I can define icon for a jquery ui button in code like this;

```
$( ".selector" ).button({ icons: {primary:'ui-icon-gear'} });
```

but I would like to define button icon in HTML code. for example

```
<a href="#" class="jqbutton ui-icon-gear">button</a>
```

this way I can only call..
    $( ".selector" ).button();
in onready event and define icons in code. otherwise I need to call button() method for every button that have different icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You could use the [Metadata Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata).**

```
<a href="#" class="jqbutton {icon: ui-icon-gear}">button</a>
```

And the script

```
$(".jqbutton")
  .each(function(){
    var data = $(this).metadata();
    $(this).button({ icons: {primary:data.icon} });
});
```

I've never used this directly, but I have used it through its support in the jquery validation plugin.

Comment: I don't know this is valid HTML but this is the thing I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped! Don't know if there are restrictions on the class attribute, but seems to work for now ; )

Answer (score 1):

The Metadata Plugin works fine, and you can even do more: you can also set **ALL** the init properties of a jQuery UI button (other widgets too):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.jq-button').each(function(){
    var meta=$(this).metadata();
    $(this).button(meta);
  });
});
</script>
<a href="#" class="jq-button {icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-new'}}">New item</a>
```

Thanks, TJB - great idea! :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can set the icon after initializing the button using the `"options"` parameter**

```
$(".jqbutton").button();
$(".jqbutton.ui-icon-gear").button( "option", "icons", 
   {primary:'ui-icon-gear'} );
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#option-icons
EDIT: the link isn't direct, so just look for the Options tab and select 'icons' then look @ the section that says 'Get or set the icons option, after init'

Comment: thank you. the problem is, I don't want to add javascript statement to onready event, each time I add a new kind of button, I would like to define icon in the markup (like adding an extra class). I think this isn't possible in ui button object.

Answer (score 0):

The following code looks for "ui-icon-*[icon-name]*" in the class-attribute of all elements containing the class "jqbutton" and creates a button with an "ui-icon-*[icon-name]*" icon.

```
$(function() {
   $(".jqbutton").each(function() {
        var obj = $(this);
        var icon = false;
        var c = obj.attr('class');
        var i1 = c.indexOf('ui-icon-');
        if (i1 != -1) {
            var i2 = c.indexOf(" ", i1);
            icon = c.substring(i1, i2 != -1 ? i2 : c.length);
            obj.removeClass(icon);
        }
        obj.button({
            icons : {
                primary : icon 
            }
        });
    });
});
```